# List of systems that are sensitive to file permissions

Tags: ssh, permissions, filesystems, logrotate

I ran into an issue on my NAS where I mistakenly reset the permissions on the root file tree to 664.

This ended up disrupting many of the NAS functions, like ssh and, after much debugging, logrotate.

My question here is: is there a list of system tools that are known to be sensitive to file permissions? It would help me create a script that resets such systems to "canonical" permissions.

Comment: "I mistakenly reset the permissions on the root file tree to 664" ... You ran `chmod -R 0644 /`? I'm surprised only ssh and logrotate broke. Any number of tools will be broken by that - if not obviously, then subtly.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what happened. I'm not sure what else broke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @muru suggests in the comments, `664` permissions for a directory are not appropriate for any "system tools."  If applied recursively, those perms are likely to break a large number of UNIX tools, not least of which the ability to search the `PATH` to find executables, etc., etc.

`mtree` is a convenient tool to back up your permissions, so that if something happens you can restore them.

As `root`, and with your permissions in a sound initial state, create a backup:

```
# mtree -c -p / > /var/backup/root-mtree.out
```

- -c ... Create an mtree specification
- -p ... Begin from path "/"

To restore your directory permissions to what was backed up:

```
mtree -u -p / < /var/backup/root-mtree.out
```

- -u ... update permissions/datestamp/flags/owner/group of entries

If you're facing this problem without having had the foresight to create an `mtree` backup first, then you may want to:

- Determine whether you do have a backup of your filesystem elsewhere, such as in a `zfs` or `btrfs` snapshot.  If so, you could take an `mtree` "impression" from the backup filesystem, and use that to restore your main filesystem.
- Create a separate installation of whatever OS on any available media (thumb drive, small hard disk on a spare computer, etc.) and again, use that as a reference to see what the permissions should be.  This base install may not contain all of the custom-created directories your production installation has
  (had), but having the base OS directories and file set correctly should go a long way toward restoring some basic functionality to your production system and better permit you to suss out what the remaining fixes are.

Comment: 664 permissions are not appropriate for any directory, not just system ones

Comment: Thanks, great suggestion. I will check the filesystem on my NAS (Synology)